# Mimicing form behavior? Opening a link with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

DHL lets you track your package on their website, like this: http://www.dhl.com/en/express/tracking.html. Now when you enter a tracking number it opens a new window like so: http://www.dhl.com/content/g0/en/express/tracking.shtml?brand=DHL&AWB=**SOMENUMBER1234**

Now I would like to mimic this behavior on my site. Where I have a form where you can enter a tracking number, and it opens the DHL url. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the new URL you've mentioned in the comments (please also update your post), you can do this with JavaScript and with a redirect through your own server.

Depending on your server-side scripting language, you may have to handle the server part differently. The following example is for PHP:

**Client HTML:**

```
<form method="GET" action="dhl_redirect.php" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="" id='myId' placeholder="Enter tracking number" />
</form>
```

**Client JavaScript:**

```
(function(){
 var form=myForm;
 form.addEventListener('submit',function(evt){
   var dhlUrl="https://dhlforyou.nl/login/track/";

   var id=document.getElementById('myId');
   if(/^\d+$/.test(id.value)){
    if(myForm.target==='_blank'){
     window.open(dhlUrl+id.value);
    }else{
     location.href=dhlUrl+id.value;
    };

   evt.preventDefault();


 },false);
})();
```

**Server:**

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['id'])&&!is_nan(intval($_GET['id']))){
  $dhlId=$_GET['id'];

  header('Location: https://dhlforyou.nl/login/track/'.dhlId);//Redirect to DHL
  exit;//Skip the rest of the script

 }else{//ID not set or not a number

    header('Location: myHTMLform.htm');
 }
?>
```

If you want to have this form open in a new tab, just set the attribute `target` to `_blank`.

Comment: Don't use `is_nan(intval(...))`, just use `empty(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just create one using a hidden value and a textbox:

```
<form method="GET" action="http://www.dhl.com/content/g0/en/express/tracking.shtml">
    <input type="hidden" name="brand" value="DHL" />
    <input type="text" name="AWB" size="{LengthOfTrackingNumber" />
</form>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I did not know the `action=""` could be on an external website.

Comment: It is worth to mention that this method opens the DHL site in the current window, and not popup window.

Comment: Yes, I was Googling for this just now :p. Doesn't look like there is a solution though. Ah well, better then nothing.

Comment: Ah darn. I'm actually trying this for a local DHL site, and it uses javascript (or something) to submit the form. Their URL looks like;

https://dhlforyou.nl/login/track/123456

Where the number is `123456`. And the best I can get is; https://dhlforyou.nl/login/track/?%2F=123456.